# How to show every backtracking of controller and views in a rails url page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## for example:

```
#app/controllers/page_controller.rb:

def page
  title
end

def title
  nil
end


#app/views/page/page.html.erb:

<%= render :partial => 'head',
```

so If we hit  http://example.com/page

this url will trigger `page` and `title` controller.  and render  `page.html.erb` and `head.html.erb`

Is there a methods to print this information in someplace of every page ?

It's a little like backtracing information.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for. The Rails console shows you what is being rendered such as partials. What are you looking for beyond that?

Comment: Is there a way can directly show on page ?  such like https://github.com/duncanbeevers/rails_view_annotator  do